# Difference between x in items and list(items) for xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.remove

Tags: python, xml.etree

Below I have a simple XML structure

```
<T1>
    <T2>
        <override select="A,B,C">
            <B>Hello</B>
        </override>
        <override select="A">
            <A>Hello</A>
        </override>
    </T2>
</T1>
```

In this example I am trying to delete any tag that is `override`.
Assuming I have the following code for setup:

```
import xml.etree.ElmenentTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()
```

If I do the following one element still persists:

```
for parent in root.iter():
    for child in parent:
        if child.tag == 'override':
            parent.remove(child)
```

However if I specify `list(parent)` instead of just `in parent`, then it works:

```
for parent in root.iter():
    for child in list(parent):
        if child.tag == 'override':
            parent.remove(child)
```

Why does this happen? If I print out `child` before I remove it, I can clearly see that the same elements are printed in both ways. So what exactly is happening here?

Comment: You are iterating over a mutable collection and changing it during iteration.  That's a no-no.  See [`for` statements](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not modify a collection while iterating over it. Python 2.7 doc doesn't explain it clearly, but here is what [Python 3 doc says](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> **Note** There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the loop (this can only occur for mutable sequences, i.e. lists). An internal counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and this is incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached the length of the sequence the loop terminates. This means that if the suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the sequence, the next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of the current item which has already been treated). Likewise, if the suite inserts an item in the sequence before the current item, the current item will be treated again the next time through the loop. This can lead to nasty bugs that can be avoided by making a temporary copy using a slice of the whole sequence